# Load list of white list domains from txt file into gitlab config

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

Can I load the list of domains from a text file into gitlab , so that only users from those domain can sign up. I dont want to enter the domains manually into gitlab , instead i want gitlab to read a text file and load those domains.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I need to do soemthing using the gitlab API.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/settings.html

Comment: This is a question and not an answer.

Comment: Gitlab API is the answer but I just need to find out the exact details in documentation